# iptables - kill established NAT connections

Tags: iptables, nat, internet-sharing

I have the following setup:

- **PC** *eth0* connected to **GW** *eth1*
- **GW** *eth0* is connected to the internet.

**GW** has `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in *sysctl.conf*

So, when I simply run (in **GW**):

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**PC** gains internet access. And when I want to disable it, I just run (in **GW**):

```
itpables -t nat -F
```

My problem is with established connections, they are not cancelled.. Example:

- **GW**: run `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
- **PC**: open http://ip-api.com/ in browser
- **GW**: run `iptables -t nat -F`
- **PC**: refresh browser -> *page is refreshed!!*

If I try a different page in **PC** it doesn't work, but due to HTTP `Connection: Keep-Alive` functionality, the browser can still use that established connection..

I could simply disable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` but I don't want to do that because of the rest of my setup.
So what I would like is to be able to get iptables (or linux NAT modules) to mess up their connection tracking so those connections become invalid or dropped...

Or is it possible to specify in iptables rules `if connection established before TIMESTAMP -j DROP` (so I could add that rule before the MASQUERADE)?

Comment: There's a utility called 'cutter' IIRC that will RST TCP connections you specify.

Answer (score 1):

example:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 513:65535 -d 202.54.1.20 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m time --timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT

So if you add  **-m time --timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT**  to your rule it will be time sensitive.

You will need to specify another rule to kill RELATED,ESTABLISHED traffic.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE -m time --timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
#if it not between these times the next rule will drop the traffic
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j ACCEPT  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m time --timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack -j DROP  --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on this relating it to my question? I cannot see how it helps as, to my understanding, this will match current time in the system and not the time the connection was established...

Comment: I have added rules above.  It compares the packet time against the system time.  If it is NOT between the times listed the RELATED,ESTABLISH connections will be dropped.

Comment: Yes, but unless I misunderstood it, it will drop looking at packet time, not at the time connection (for that packet) was established so it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: You did misunderstand.  If the time, not the packet time, is after **timestop** the traffic is dropped.  It doesn't matter when the connection was established, at 18:00 hours it WILL be dropped.  **PERIOD**

Comment: Exactly, so I did understand. This does not answer my question.